# Is there a way to pass a github actions workflow job on addition of a PR label?

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions, pull-request, danger

I am using danger to check for specific label being added, and on that check being true I then want to pass a workflow job which was previously failing e.g.

```js
 const gitHubLabels = danger.github.issue.labels.map((label) => label.name.trim());
 const codeOwnerLabel = gitHubLabels.find((label) => label === 'CODE OWNER APPROVED');
 
 if (codeOwnerLabel) {
   // pass/ignore specific workflow job here
 }
```

There is this github endpoint https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#list-jobs-for-a-workflow-run which lists all jobs and I can then use this to check for specific job but there is no endpoint to then pass that job somehow.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the listForRef API (https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#checks) gives information on the particular job check run so now I have the information to write my logic.